# i got an error in my forms.py file of project

Tags: python, django, typeerror

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from matplotlib import widgets
from .models import *

class Userregistration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password','name','email_id','contact','address']
        widgets={
            'username':forms.CharField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'name':forms.CharField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email_id':forms.EmailField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'contact':forms.CharField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'address':forms.CharField(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

it is showing me typeerror:'__init()'got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

Answer (score 2):

A [**`CharField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#charfield) is *not* a widget, it is a *form field. The default widget for a `CharField` is a [**`TextInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) and for an [**`EmailField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#emailfield) it is an [**`EmailInput`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.EmailInput):

```
class Userregistration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password','name','email_id','contact','address']
        widgets={
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email_id':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'contact':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'address':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Django `forms.CharField()` is not a widget. So change your `CharField` as `TextInput`. You can see [Built-in widgets[Django Doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/widgets/#built-in-widgets) for more details.

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators
from matplotlib import widgets
from .models import *

class Userregistration(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=['username','password','name','email_id','contact','address']
        widgets={
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'password':forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email_id':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'contact':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'address':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
        }
```

Comment: My pleasure @Mansi Raval

Answer (score 0):

`attrs` is not an argument to the field, it's an argument to the widget.

```
file = forms.FileField(widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'File'}))
```

Comment: now it is showing me typeerror: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'